# ProcessPurchase event get called multiple times - Unity IAP

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Before I have purchased Weekly Subscription and now whenever I open my app again, ProcessPurchase event get called multiple times. Though this time I have purchased nothing.

See below xCode log for more clearance:
[image]

Now I have just open the app so no reason for event get called multiple times by itself.
As per my thinking, it should get call only one time when ever you make purchase something.
Then after there is no reason of this callback.

Mainly I was following this document and its code:
[Integrating Unity IAP In Your Game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game)

Here is my snippet of code:

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
{
    if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDPick_099, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDPick_199, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDPick_299, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDPick_399, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDPick_499, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDWeeklySubscription, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));

        SubscriptionActivated();

        //if (DataStorage.RetrieveLoggedInStatus() == GameConstants.ON)
        //    StartCoroutine(CheckForSubscriptionStatus());
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDMonthlySubscription, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));

        SubscriptionActivated();
        //if (DataStorage.RetrieveLoggedInStatus() == GameConstants.ON)
        //    StartCoroutine(CheckForSubscriptionStatus());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }

    return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
}

private void SubscriptionActivated()
{
    GameManager.Instance.IsSubscriptionRunning = true;
    if (paidPickParser != null)
        paidPickParser.UnlockAllPaidPicks();
    Camera.main.SendMessage("ActivateSubscriptionDialog", false, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

Before I have made purchase of Weekly Subscription.
Another point, why I was getting NullReferenceException through internal method? See above log image for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving multiple transactions / purchase events because you are using auto-renewable subscriptions. In sandbox (Apple's purchase test environment) subscription periods [are accelerated](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html) to help with testing.

Comment: Thank you sir for quick reply :) So in Sandbox mode multiple transaction was happened (Weekly - 3 mins time limit) so all those executed when I have opened the app, am I correct for this? What is the reason for NullReferenceException?

Comment: Yep, your understanding is correct. I don't know about the NRE though, good luck.

Comment: But one thing, I have noticed - now at every app launch its calling singles time not more than that. So exactly how many time auto renew purchase get called in background?

Comment: Also in real purchase same thing get happened, for ex. month later a method get 4 times because of 4 weeks. So how to handle this scenario ?

Comment: Unity support replied to me - they require to update their plugin regarding this. https://forum.unity.com/threads/processpurchase-event-get-called-multiple-times.506574/#post-3304022